# c++ socket receive image and showing without saving

Tags: c++, sockets, opencv

I want to receive a image from client.

We can show the image at server side when we save it to a JPG file.

Like this...

```
    char *buff = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (240*360));    
    FILE *output;    
    output = fopen("test.jpg", "wb");    
    unsigned int readBytes = 0;    
    while(true)    
    {    
        int ret = recv(sClient, buff+readBytes, (240*360)-readBytes, 0);    
        if (ret <= 0)    
        {    
            break;    
        }    
                readBytes += ret;    
    }    
    fwrite(buff, sizeof(char), readBytes, output);    
    fclose( output );    

    Mat img_2 = imread( "test.jpg");
```

But is there any way to get the Mat of received image directly by received char* ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But is there any way to get the Mat of received image directly by received char* ??"

yes, there is. instead of saving to disk and reloading, you could use [imdecode()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode)